# Reading external variable from internal function

Tags: javascript, scope

I have a code like this:

```
function main() {
    this.var1 = 1;
    function internal() {
        //some function supposed to work on var1
    }
    this.x = new internal();
}
var m = new main();

function main2() {
    m.x.someFunction(); //need to change m.var1
}
```

Is there a way to access to var1 from internal(), **without passing it as argument**? 
I know I could just do: `var var1 = 1;`, and then in internal() i could put something like `var1 += blabla;`, but doing so will set var1 to a local variable and it won't be seen anymore by main2() function. Furthermore I could even declare var1 as global, but I need it to be a property of main(). So, I can't set var1 as a local or global variable, I can't set internal() as a global function or as a method of main.

I hope some one knows how to "extend" the scope of var1 inside internal()

Comment: You can't do this. This would be a huge violation of OOP.

Comment: That's what I didn't want to hear... Then argument all the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with this?

```
function main() {
    var var1 = 1;
    function internal() {
        //some function supposed to work on var1
    }
    this.var1 = var1;
    this.x = new internal();
}
```

Or possibly this:

```
function main() {
    this.var1 = 1;
    function internal(me) {
        //some function supposed to work on me.var1
    }
    this.x = new internal(this);
}
```

Comment: But every time I call internal, it would just change var1 not this.var1 because "this.var1 = var1" would be executed only during the creation of an object of main. Then i would need to "update" this.var1, making simply useless the function internal()... am I wrong??

Comment: The second one instead is what I thought to do, but I was looking for a solution without any argument, that i was answered to be not possible. So that's what I will do, thank you :P

Comment: You've only defined `internal` in the scope of `main`. It can't be called from anywhere else. (Unless you use `.constructor`, which isn't very nice.) If you want to call `internal` again later you should rearrange your code. In that case, yes, you're right in saying that `internal` wouldn't behave as intended if called after `this.var1=var1;`.

Comment: Yes sorry, I meant when I call some method of an instance of internal.. I can't use m.x.someFunction() to change m.var1